# Как словить несколько подряд брошенных исключений?

Tags: исключения, java

Пытался нагуглить, вываливается куча стандартных статей по исключениям, даже скипи не помог)). Рылся в своих заметках, не смог найти, как обработать такое исключение, чтобы вывести информацию по каждому:

> throw new Exception("AAA", new
> RuntimeException("BBB", new
> IllegalAccessException("CCC")));

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `exception.getCause()`

Comment: Точно)) Спасибо!
В моем случае:
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        System.out.println(e.getCause().getCause());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы всегда можете поймать только одно конкретное исключение в конкретный момент времени. Приведенный вами пример, это одно исключение, связанное с другими, ранее выброшенными и перехваченными исключеиями (chained exceptions).

Соотвествтенно вам достаточно поймать исключение типа `Exception`. Если же ваша логика обработки зависит от типа исходного исключения, вы всегда можете получиь его с помощью метода `getCause`.

К слову сказать, стандартные методы вывода информации об исключениях всегда выводят в том числе и вложенные исключения.